# Postgresql: How to calculate AVE & SUM of prices in different currencies?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of products in DB as follows:

Table1:

```
product_id | price | currency
1          | 230   | EUR
2          | 110   | EUR
3          | 100   | USD
4          | 80    | EUR
5          | 450   | PESO
6          | 200   | GBP
7          | 75    | USD
```

Here I would like to calculate average prices and SUM prices in USD.

Do you have any idea how it may be possible in Postgresql query?

Comment: If you want to calculate the prices in USD for *all* of those regardless of the currency set there, then you'll need to know the exchange rate.

Comment: I know I need to provide exchange rates as an input but I am looking for the sql query.

Comment: Please include expected output in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have exchange ratios somewhere. For example:

```
create table exchange (from_curr char(4), to_curr char(4), ratio numeric);
insert into exchange values ('EUR', 'USD', 1.17), ('USD','USD',1), ('PESO','USD',0.051), ('GBP','USD',1.32);
```

Then just do the query joining both tables:

```
select sum(p.price * e.ratio) usd_sum, avg(p.price * e.ratio) usd_avg from product p, exchange e where p.currency = e.from_curr and e.to_curr='USD';
 usd_sum |       usd_avg        
---------+----------------------
 953.350 | 136.1928571428571429
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer

Comment: This makes the assumption that currency rates for items of the same rate are equal, which doesn't have to be the case. For instance the EUR rows might be from different times, giving them different currency rates. What you need to do is store the rates in your products table for every items you have using a new column.